# How to intercept write operations on a QVector?

Tags: c++, qt5

**First things first: I know extending from containers is a BAD practice & I also know the reasons why.** On the other hand, I'm "playing the code I've been dealt" and there is no time to refactor it properly.

I have a class, let's call it `VectorOfSomethings`, extended from `QVector<Something>`. Each `Something` has a `hashCode()` method, which uniquely identifies it.

On the other hand, there are a lot of other classes having members of the type `VectorOfSomethings` and there are a lot of `operator == implemented` as `m_Somethings == other.m_Somethings`. These operators get called A LOT.

Since there is no actual way to eagerly compute the hashes, I have to rely on the `VectorOfSomethings::hashCode()` method, which goes through all the currently stored Somethings and, based on their hashes, calculates the hash of the collection, on the spot. This is super expensive.

**What would be the most efficient way to intercept all write operations to VectorOfSomethings, so every time a Something is added/removed to/from it, the hash is recalculated & cached, to have it ready for the operator==, when required?**

Tried overloading the original QVector methods. Very inelegant. In some situations doesn't work (which is way worse than inelegant).

This is a schematic of how the code looks now:

```cpp
class VectorOfSomething : public QVector<Something>, public SomeOtherNonEssentials
{
  public:

    // Insert other methods here

    uint hashCode() const {
      uint result = 0;
      std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(), [&result](Something value) {
        result = regenerateHash(result, value.hashCode());
      });

      return result;
    }

    bool operator==(const VectorOfSomething &other) const
    {
      return hashCode() == other.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not inherit from Qt containers (same as STL ones, they are not designed to be inherited, one hint is that they don't have virtual destructor).

So, use composition and provide the required interface for the internal vector, this will also solve your problem, it will intercept all modifications:

```
//Optional make it generic
class VectorOfSomething : public SomeOtherNonEssentials
{
  public:
    // Insert other methods here
    // insert methods like insert/remove/add/push_back 
    void push_back(const Something& something)
    {
      //do whatever with something
      m_internalVector.push_back(something);
    }
  private:
    QVector<Something> m_internalVector;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely the right way to do it, but it's, unfortunately, not something that can be called efficient. For the moment, we have to use the current code base and the code expects full conversion from QVector<Something> to VectorOfSomething. I'm looking for a temporary efficient solution to mitigate this issue.